# Understanding partial expectation.

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

I am new to probability and statistics, I am reading an article on survival analysis and when defining the expectation of a parametric model, log-normal distribution, the author used the partial expectation. I did a research and found nothing significant, or rather nothing that provide me with a good understanding, so what is that partial expectation, definition, properties. Thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partial expectation is a measure concerning a portion of the standard normal distribution; either on the right-hand side or on the left-hand side of the standard normal.
you can read more in [this](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-76042-1_4) link.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Partial_expectation) section on partial expectation of the lognormal distribution to be a superior reference, since it:

1. gives a clear mathematical definition
2. is not paywalled
3. fits with the original question's context in regard to survival models and lognormal distributions
4. is presumably more stable as a link for future reference than a publisher's link to an abstract.

For the sake of completeness, the partial expectation of a continuous random variable $X$ is given by $$\operatorname{E}[X \mid X > k]\Pr[X > k] = \int_{x=k}^\infty x f_X(x) \, dx.$$